# Convert year-month into Date while GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have column in Dataframe that is PERIOD and it is in format of:

```
PERIOD   ACTUAL
202201   343.34 
202202   545.33
202203   54
202201   989.2
```

It means in DMY format 01-01-2022, 01-02-2022, 01-03-2022

I am using it inside:

```
groupedResult = df.groupby('PERIOD')['Actual'].sum()
```

How I can convert PERIOD values into Dates in Python?

I have tried to proceed with, but got stuck:

```
groupedResult = df.groupby(datetime('PERIOD'.year, 'PERIOD'.month, 1))['Actual'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question wasn't totally clear as didn't have a workable example but I've had a crack at it here for you with data I made up:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'period':['202201','202201','202201','202201','202202','202202','202203'], 'actuals':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("BEFORE:")
```

This gives period as you described but it's stored as object and not datetime:

```
BEFORE:
   period  actuals
0  202201       10
1  202201       20
2  202201       30
3  202201       40
4  202202       50
5  202202       60
6  202203       70
print(df)
```

Here `format='%Y%m'` converts it to datetime (%Y%m means search for YYYYMM in the incoming string). Then `.dt.strftime('%Y/%m')` converts it back to an object format type but in the date format you require.

```
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['period'], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y/%m')

print("AFTER:")
groupedresults = df.groupby('period')['actuals'].sum()
print(groupedresults)
```

And here's your output. Change the date format of period to suit your needs:

```
AFTER:
period
2022/01    100
2022/02    110
2022/03     70
Name: actuals, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! I have forgot to mention that I also have empty cells = values in PERIOD column. Could you please help with at? With provided solution I am getting an errors. `time data '' does not match format '%Y%m' (match)` 
How to skip these? Need to use numpy for that?

Comment: Add `errors='coerce'` to to_datetime:

`df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['period'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y/%m')`

This will produce NaN in place of your missing dates.